# What causes the yolk of a frozen egg to be more spreadable instead of fluid?

Tags: organic-chemistry

If you freeze an egg the yolk of it gets more spreadable instead of it was fluid before. It appears that this state of the yolk is perm. So what chemical reaction causes this?

The question is of course after the egg had been melted again.

Comment: Can you rephrase this question? It's not clear what you mean by "spreadable" or "perm".

Comment: with spreadable I mean that the yolk had become more solid and perm means that it stays in that solid shape and not becomes fluid again after it is melted for a while.

Comment: OK, but neither of that is an English word.

Comment: Spreadable: with the capability of being spread. Perm: a contraction of 'permanent', most often used in relation to permanent hair colouring. They are definitely both English words even if you didn't know them.